# PHP: Tagging an object

Tags: php, variables, element

I have an object, with a name, and I am wondering how to tag it, in Javascript for example, you would put

getElementByID("ElementHere")

How would you do this in PHP? This is what I have:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<BODY>
<FORM method="POST" name="passcheck">
Blah blah blah...
</FORM>
<?php
$obj = this.document:getElementByID("passcheck")
?>
</BODY>
</HEAD>
</HTML>
```

Would this be possible somehow in PHP?

Also, if you come up with an answer, could you please show it as an example?

Thanks

Comment: you want to *create* an element?

Comment: you want to access a dom object within PHP?

Comment: PHP doesn't work like that... I'd like to help you but I wouldn't know where to begin.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish after you "tag" the element?

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById` (note **Id** not ID) will get an element by its id, not by its name.  Replace the name attribute with an id attribute. If you really want to use a name attribute then you would need to loop over `getElementsByName`.

In PHP, if you are simply outputting the HTML with embedded PHP in it, then you can't modify arbitrary points of the document — only those where you have explicit PHP code in place — (unless it is possible to turn output buffering on and then modify the contents of the buffer, but if that is possible then it is madness and you would be better off re-architecting the system anyway).

Given a separate HTML document, then you just need to load it into a [DOM engine](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) and then you can use [standard DOM methods](http://www.w3.org/DOM/DOMTR) which work in the same way as they do from JavaScript.